# Layout File for LyX

Tags: lyx-layouts

I want to use a new class in LyX. I know where to save the .cls file so that LyX can use it. I have already done that. I also know that I need a layout file and need to save it in the layout folders. My problem is that I do not know which software to use to write the layout file. Any answers?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! lyx?

Comment: @Zarko http://lyx.org - a graphical frontend to LaTeX.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., yes, i assume that op have/use only Lyx. i would write it with standard `latex`. or i misunderstand question?

Comment: See Help > Customization > Ctrl+R > Chapter five. The layout is a simple plain text. Any text editor is good for this.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, you seem to have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., i must confess that i'm noot familiar with lyx. i assume, that in it you can write `.sty` files (if "template" means this). apparently i'm wrong (and this is one thing more why i not use lyx :-) )

Comment: @Zarko LyX is not really a text editor, you can't (easily) write a `.sty` file in it, and a layout file is not the same as a `.sty` file, other than both being plain text files.

Answer (score 1):

A `.layout` file is just a plain text file, so use any plain text editor. E.g. Notepad, Gedit, Kate, Textedit, Notepad++, Sublime Text, Atom, Vim, Emacs etc. Whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks.When you save a Notepad file, the file extension is .text not .layout. Notepad does not give the option to change the extension of the file. Is there a way to save a file created with Notepad with a .layout extension?

Comment: @LyX2394 Can't you select "All files" or something, and type `.layout`? (Haven't opened Notepad in years.) Alternatively just rename the file afterwards.

Comment: @LyX2394 Seems an alternative is to type filename with extension in quotes (http://lifehacker.com/5883860/change-the-file-extension-of-any-file-through-windows-save-as-menu), i.e. write `"something.layout"` as filename, and even if `.txt` is selected as filetype, the file will be called `something.layout`, not `something.layout.txt`.